# CORS issues for Flask API call from React both in localhost

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, cors, axios

I am calling a Flask API from React (both running on localhost) and I am running into CORS problems.
When the request is made, the browser (Chrome) gives the following error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/sas' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

## Setup

The Flask setup is the following

```
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask import Flask, request, Response
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
import json

class SAS(Resource):
    def get(self):
        content = request.json
        js = json.dumps(
            {
                "Response": "Some response"
            }
        )
        resp = Response(js, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
        return resp

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(SAS, '/sas/')
```

The call using axios in React is the following

```
  buttonPressed = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/sas`, {
      data: {
        user: "user",
        file_name: "user",
        directory_name: "user"
      }
    });
  };
```

NOTE: Running the request from Postman works and shows the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin = *`

Any idea on how to solve the problem?

Also, if I was to run the React frontend and API as a dockerized application, I should not see this problem anymore correct? In this case I would also consider circumnavigating the problem while I am developing

Comment: Is this relevant? https://github.com/corydolphin/flask-cors/issues/200

Comment: Thanks @Pitto for pointing that out. I came across that page before, however it didn't help resolving the issue unfortunately

Answer (score 4):

Please try using the cross_origin decorator like in this minimal example:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, support_credentials=True)

@app.route('/sas', methods=['POST', 'GET', 'OPTIONS'])
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def index():
    if(request.method=='POST'):
     some_json = request.get_json()
     return jsonify({"key": some_json})
    else:
        return jsonify({"GET": "Nice Get Request"})

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

If this works then we'll move to implement the same decorator in your code.

Comment: Thanks @Pitto, but still not working. The error is now slightly different

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/sas/' (redirected from 'http://localhost:5000/sas') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

Comment: I was finally able to send a request from React using your suggestion but also modifying the React Request to send to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/sas` rather than `http://localhost:5000/sas` (why should it be different anyway?).

Still not working however using `flask_restful`

Comment: Hi @GZZ . Please consider upvoting my answer and / or selecting it as final answer if it was useful for you. Thanks!

Comment: @GZZ can you post your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same CORS issue in my application. Despite trying numerous solutions and exhaustively exploring the suggestions provided here, I couldn't resolve the issue.

Then, in the course of my attempts to restart my Python server, I noticed that it wasn't booting up. On further investigation, I discovered a process occupying port 5000. Using the command lsof -i :5000, I found the following output:

```
ControlCe 458 austinsoftware    7u  IPv4 0xc4d6bbbf886db801      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
```

After researching what this ControlCe process might be, it turned out to be related to AirPlay Receiver. Disabling AirPlay Receiver in the System Preferences under the 'Sharing' tab freed up port 5000.

Once this was done, my Python server was able to run properly on port 5000 without the previous CORS error. So, if you encounter a similar issue, it's worth checking to see if there's a process like AirPlay Receiver or any other service that might be occupying the server's designated port.

Always remember, the causes of CORS issues are not just limited to your server-side or client-side code configuration, but may also be due to system-level processes interfering with your server's operation.